# How to add server controls into Kentico unigrid?

Tags: c#, kentico, unigrid

I have looked up everywhere in Kentico 8 documentations and I couldn't find any information regarding add server or html controls within UniGrid.

I need to add a simple check box or a drop down list in one of the UniGrid columns but I can't find any ways to do that!
the only thing that I found was `GridOptions.ShowSelection` which is a general selection for selecting each row that I don't need.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can jump into the event OnExternalDataBound in the Unigrid codebehind see for example https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/advanced-unigrid-example.

An create here dynamic a new web part or a user control.

For example:

In your XML you have this column

```
<column source="##ALL##" externalsourcename="yourcolumn" caption="" wrap="false" />
```

Then in your codebehind of the UniGrid

```
protected object UniGrid_OnExternalDataBound(object sender, string sourceName, object parameter)
{
    ContextResolver resolver = CMSContext.CurrentResolver.CreateContextChild();
    DataRowView drv;

    switch (sourceName.ToLower())
    {
        case "yourcolumn":
            drv = (DataRowView)parameter;
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chkDoc";
            chk.CssClass = "normalcheckbox";
            chk.InputAttributes.Add("Value", ValidationHelper.GetString(drv["NodeGUID"], string.Empty));
            return chk;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How might you get the value of "chkDoc" in a unigrid's OnAction function?